# S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 to successfully copy S3 objects to GLACIER_IR storage class with the following code:

`copy_source = {'Bucket': obj['Bucket'], 'Key': obj['Key']}`

`s3.copy(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=bucket, Key=filename_w_timestamp, StorageClass='GLACIER_IR')`

However, when I use a very similar code to retrieve the above file back, I get the following error:

`botocore.errorfactory.ObjectNotInActiveTierError: An error occurred (ObjectNotInActiveTierError) when calling the CopyObject operation: The source object of the COPY operation is not in the active tier and is only stored in Amazon Glacier.`

Here is the piece of code I am using to attempt retrieval:

```
s3.copy(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=bucket, Key=filename_w_timestamp)
```

Can someone please help out with what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Just because it is in "Instant Retrieval" doesn't meant that it is accessible with normal S3 commands. To access data that is stored in Glacier, you need to call [`restore_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/restore_object.html): _"Restores an archived copy of an object back into Amazon S3"_ It will then be (temporarily) stored as a Standard object and can be used like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the tip John Rotenstein.
For future me and others, I change my code to following and now it works.

```
copy_source = {
            'Bucket': obj['Bucket'],
            'Key': obj['Key']
        }

# Restore the object from Glacier Instant Retrieval tier
s3.restore_object(Bucket=obj['Bucket'], Key=obj['Key'], RestoreRequest={'Days': 1})

# Wait for the object to be restored (This may take some time)
waiter = s3.get_waiter('object_exists')
waiter.wait(Bucket=obj['Bucket'], Key=obj['Key'])

# Copy the object to the Standard tier bucket
s3.copy_object(Bucket=dest_bucket, CopySource=copy_source, Key=obj['Key'])
```

Comment: I would note that `s3.download_file` works as usual.